# Is there an R function for exporting list and sub-list names in a data table?

Tags: r

I have the below output from a function.

```
DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`1`
[1] 0.016082

DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`2`
[1] 0.025863

DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`3`
[1] 0.036965
```

I want to make a data table with 2 columns, one is ID and another one is the output:

```
ID                         Var1
DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`1`  0.016082
DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`2`  0.025863
DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`3`  0.036965
```

Example,

```
DT <- data.table (A=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5), B=c(200,210,300,420,289,365,587,250,110,500,800), C=c(0.6,0.35,0.6,0.85,0.22,0.36,0.39,0.31,0.33,0.58,0.66))
DT
DT_Split <- split(DT, DT$A)
names(DT_Split) <- c(paste("FF", names(DT_Split), sep = ""))
list2env(DT_Split, .GlobalEnv)
lapply(DT_Split, function(x){
  x[, NewColumn := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(B) < 0))]})
DT_Split2 <- lapply(DT_Split, function(x) split(x, x$NewColumn))

REREG<-lapply(DT_Split2, 
                function(x) {lapply(x,  function(x) {summary(lm(formula=B~C,data=x))})})

REREG_R2<-lapply(REREG, function(x){lapply(x, function(x){
      x$r.squared})})
```

The output for REREG_R2 is:

```
$FF1
$FF1$`1`
[1] 0.1758242


$FF2
$FF2$`1`
[1] 0

$FF2$`2`
[1] 0


$FF3
$FF3$`1`
[1] 1


$FF4
$FF4$`1`
[1] 0

$FF4$`2`
[1] 1


$FF5
$FF5$`1`
[1] 0
```

I can make a data table for variables, but I couldn't extract and add IDs.
I appreciate any code that can help me to do that.

Thanks in advance,
Milad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `stack` in `base R`

```
stack(lstout)[2:1]
#                      ind   values
#1 DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`1` 0.016082
#2 DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`2` 0.025863
#3 DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`3` 0.036965
```

---

Or using `enframe`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)  
enframe(lstout) %>% 
     unnest(c(value))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  name                       value
#  <chr>                      <dbl>
#1 DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`1` 0.0161
#2 DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`2` 0.0259
#3 DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`3` 0.0370
```

#### Update

If the data is highly nested, use `rrapply`

```
library(rrapply)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
rrapply(DataSet, how = "melt") %>% 
       unite(ID, L1, L2, L3, sep = '$') %>%
       mutate(ID = str_c('DataSet$', ID)) %>%
       rename(Var1 = value)
#                   ID     Var1
#1 DataSet$DataSet01$1$1 0.016082
#2 DataSet$DataSet01$1$2 0.025863
#3 DataSet$DataSet01$1$3 0.036965
#4 DataSet$DataSet02$1$1 0.016082
#5 DataSet$DataSet02$1$2 0.025863
#6 DataSet$DataSet02$1$3 0.036965
```

---

Or using `rapply` from `base R`

```
stack(rapply(REREG_R2, as.data.frame))[2:1]
```

#### data

```
lstout <- list("DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`1`" = 0.016082,
               "DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`2`" = 0.025863,
                "DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`3`" = 0.036965)

DataSet <- list(DataSet01 = list(`1` = list(`1` = 0.016082, `2` = 0.025863, 
`3` = 0.036965)), DataSet02 = list(`1` = list(`1` = 0.016082, 
`2` = 0.025863, `3` = 0.036965)))
```

Comment: I am using `stack(lst(DataSet)) ` is that correct? But I just realised that I can see the `DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`1` ` but not as `ind`. I can see `DataSet` for all rows as `ind`. So, I cannot extract `DataSet$DataSet01$`1`$`1`

Comment: @Milad Can you please update your post with a small reproducible example.  I thought your data a a named list

Comment: @Milad is it possible to get a small example `dput`

Comment: @Milad Do you have somethiing like `Dataset <- lst(Dataset01 = lst(`1` = lst(`1` = 0.016082, `2` = 0.025863, `3` = 0.036965)), Dataset02 = lst(`1` = lst(`1` = 0.016082, `2` = 0.025863, `3` = 0.036965)))`

Comment: Thanks, I am sorting my results to add and update my question.

Comment: @Milad I guess this `rrapply(REREG_R2, how = "melt") %>% unite(ID, L1, L2, sep="$") %>% mutate(ID = str_c('REREG_R2$', ID)) %>% rename(Var1 = value)` works for me as per your original requirement

Comment: @Milad if you need a nestted two column dataset, use `enframe(REREG_R2)`

Comment: `rrapply` works fine, is there any function (base R) that I can use it instead of `rrapply` , ` ... ` ?

Comment: @Milad with highly recursive objects, you may have to create a recursive function with `rapply` (from `base R`)

Comment: @Milad try with `stack(rapply(REREG_R2, as.data.frame))[2:1]`